# Importing posts only - consequences?

Tags: posts, import, export, bulk-import

One of my client holds a slow Internet connection. So he wants to do all his web updates locally (by any means - he doesn't understand codes) and then he wants to update the website by any *easy and quick means*.

Now I's thinking to

make him a `localhost` setup in his PC, and setting up everything like his web servers. Then I'll let him to do all his updates in localhost, and then `Tools > Export > All Posts` (posts only). With this `.xml` file then he will import the file into the web server simply by `Tools > Import`. :)

But is it Ok from all aspects - I think, I'm probably missing some bad consequences-

- What about the uploaded image files, will they be uploaded into the `../uploads/..` folder?
- What about the maximum execution time exceeds ERROR - and some missing `posts/media`?
- What about duplicate posts, media entry etc. *(is it really possible? - I don't think so, but...)*?
- etc.

I've bad experiences regarding such import <> export things - it duplicated my custom menus and even duplicated the WordPress's default post (*Hello World!*) and Page (*Single Page*).

So, under this circumstances, **am I thinking in the right way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not export and import posts as a remote publishing strategy. That is going to be a lot of trouble and probably prone to error. You will also have issues with media uploads that you will have to sync between the local and remote servers and with file URLs that you will have to constantly update with something like [Velvet Blues Update URLs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/). I expect that there are issues that I am not think of right now, or that you yourself did not list.

What you want is [XML/RPC Remote Publishing](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) via a [Weblog Client](http://codex.wordpress.org/Weblog_Client). I have never used any and so cannot recommend any, but what you describe is what that remote publishing system + client is meant to do.

Comment: +1 for desktop client, I have used Windows Live Writer pretty much exclusively to post for couple years.

Comment: @Rarst: Thanks for an assurance at least. May we have some DETAILS about your experience with Windows Live Writer > WordPress as an answer here? :) Especially, I have many custom fields in my client's project.

Comment: I've downloaded and installed WLW but it holds the basic WP post editor. It doesn't support custom fields. Do you know any that supports custom fields?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam sorry, only wrote posts with it